# VisualStudio WPF. Adding a folder into output directory

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I need to create a Folder with Wallpapers. This needs to be placed into the output directory so that users can then add their own images.

So my question is:

How can i place a folder in my output directory? (this should work in debug and release)

For the second part of the question I can handle on my own, which would be to bring all the items in that folder and present it to the user to chose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting items in the folder in your project (assuming you have some default wallpapers) to `Build Action = Content`, `Copy to Output Directory = Copy Always/Copy if Newer` will place them inside that same folder structure in your output directory. If you don't already have files there you could add something like a ReadMe.txt with instructions on adding images that could serve the same purpose.

Comment: Ok, but is there any way I can do this in an organised fashion? I want to be able to put a folder called wallpapers. I just want to avoid having all my related files (images, dll, xml, etc) in one big directory. I would like it to be structured and neat. This is why I wanted to copy a folder and place images into that.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for that's different from my answer. If you put a folder structure under your project's node in VS and have files in it set as above, that folder structure will be duplicated in your build output.

Answer (score 0):

Add a folder to your project and then set its Copy To Output Directory property appropriately.

Comment: a Folder does not have properties. I can only do this on a file basis. any suggestions?

Comment: B*gger!  I didn't have VS handy to check when I posted that but I thought it was the case.  How are you deploying the app?

Comment: I have not at the deployment stage just yet so I haven't really thought about it. maybe clickonce or by installer. not sure.